# How do I re-use named scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

Hi I have a `named_scope` in my `User` model as following.

```
named_scope :by_gender, lamdba { |gender| { :conditions => { :gender => gender } } }
```

I want to create other two named scopes which re use this one something like,

```
named_scope :male,   lambda { by_gender('male') }
named_scope :female, lambda { by_gender('female') }
```

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide class methods that perform the hardwired argument passing:

```
def self.male
    by_gender('male')
end

def self.female
    by_gender('female')
end
```

or, as the named_scope you are using is so simple you could cut out the by_gender scope and simply use:

```
named_scope :male, :conditions => {:gender => 'male'}
named_scope :female, :conditions => {:gender => 'female'}
```

The second option is of course conditional on you not actually requiring the by_gender scope explicitly anywhere else.

Comment: Hmmm providing class methods makes sense. It will return an association proxy so I can even chain them together. Thanks.